# Deployment: incorrect character encoding

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, deployment

I'm having issues when deploying my MVC3-application as Swedish characters appear as if read with wrong encoding; å becomes Ã¥, ä Ã¤, ö Ã¥ and so forth.

The application is UTF-8 encoded and works fine when running on the local IIS server, so this problem has to be the destination environment.

Do you have any ideas as to how I can solve this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check that destination IIS server encoding setting match your local ones ?

See here to find out about Globalization Settings : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771836%28WS.10%29.aspx

Kris

Comment: That did it. I just had to set the globalization settings from en-US to sv-SE. Great, thanks!